# How to iterate a list with itemtap (sencha touch 2)

Tags: dictionary, extjs, loops, marker

I would like to know how to use itemtap to iterate through a list. I have a list right now which shows multiple items and when the user clicks on each, a map will appear showing the marker of the item. However, every item on the list seems to be showing the same thing. It is just showing the latest item on the list (first at the top). I would like to know what I'm doing wrong with the itemtap function. Thank You!!

Heres my controller where the itemtap function is:

```
Ext.define('demo.controller.News',{
extend:'Ext.app.Controller',

config:{
    refs:{
        NewsContainer:'newscontainer'

    },
    control:{
        'newscontainer new list':{
            itemtap:function(list, index, target, record){
                var detailsView = Ext.create('demo.view.Mapo');
                detailsView.setData(record.data);
                this.getNewsContainer().push(detailsView);

            }
        }

    }   
}
```

});

And here is my map:

```
Ext.define('demo.view.Mapo', {
extend: 'Ext.Map',
xtype:'mapo',
config: {
    title:'Incident Location',
    iconCls:'maps',
    layout:'fit',
    draggable: true,
    useCurrentLocation: true,
    mapOptions: {
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
},
initialize: function(){
    var me = this;
    me.on('maprender', function(comp, map){
    var image = 'resources/images/current.png';
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    this._geo.getLatitude(), 
                    this._geo.getLongitude()
            ),
            icon: image,
            map: map,
            title: "Current Location",
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });


        //Circle Radius
        // var populationOptions = {
        // strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        // strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        // strokeWeight: 1,
        // fillColor: "#FF0000",
        // fillOpacity: 0.35,
        // map: map,
        // center: new google.maps.LatLng(this._geo.getLatitude(), 
                            // this._geo.getLongitude()),
        // radius: 2000
        // };
        // var t = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);


    for (i=0; i<Ext.getStore('news').getData().length; i++){

        var data = Ext.getStore('news').getData().items[i].data
    };
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    data.Latitude, 
                    data.Longitude
            ),
            // icon: image,
            map: map,
            title: "Incident Location",
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });


    });
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Comment: Guys any help? Been stuck on this for days! =(

Comment: If you look at the comments for http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List the args are not consistant ( the comments seem to imply that the api docs are wrong ). Try logging your arguments in your itemtap, to make sure that the order actaully IS `(list, index, target, record)`